# Help Identifying this Magento Theme (Reward)

Tags: magento-1.9

A client of mine is adamant that I use the theme located at (http://www.7diamonds.com). I've tried inspecting the element but they have left not traces of the theme used. They also do not cache.

So I'm pretty lost as to how I should go about finding this theme. If one of you heroes out there can identify this theme I'd be more than willing to reward you via PayPal.

Edit: Lemme add some more info. They've renamed the theme package so I'm not sure if you can simply identify the theme by just inspecting the page. I'll reward you generously if someone is able to figure this out. Thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: they have rename the theme package and theme name , so its hard to find without sourcecode

Comment: yep I realize. that's why I figured I should add a reward.

Answer (score 0):

you go to the system->configuration->general->design there define which theme is used in your site.

Comment: I don't own the website. It's somebody else's.

Comment: its 7diamonds theme

Comment: Well I know it's their theme, but I also have reason to believe that it isn't a custom theme. I'm thinking they purchased it somewhere online, and I'd like to find it.

Comment: i think its a sebian theme.

Answer (score 0):

The site is awful in terms of loading, it constantly throws 504 errors. I've tried my luck however and I'm 90% sure this is a custom theme. The css & Js files don't look theme-ish, they look very specific. You can see all the static resources if you access http://www.7diamonds.com/skin/frontend - there's a default/7diamonds theme and a 7diamonds/7diamonds theme. They both have some plugin resources, but nothing that look like a theme.

I'd recommend going for the latest magento 1.x version and use madisonisland (rwd) theme. you can customize it to fit your needs - you would probably need to purchase some of the extension this site is using (gomage navigation, ajaxcart). even if i'm wrong and this is a paid theme, it's heavily modified, so you would still need to customize it...